# Exchange a 0 value for value next to it in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
Variable_1=c(123,0,12,0,334)
Variable_2=c(100,212,13,112,300)
df=data.frame(Variable_1,Variable_2)
```

Ideally I would like to replace the `0` values in `Variable_1` with the neighboring value from `Variable_2` to get the following:

```
Variable_1=c(123,212,12,112,334)
Variable_2=c(100,212,13,112,300)
```

I have tried the following:

```
df$Variable_1[df$Variable_1 == 0] <- df$Variable_2
```

The problem that I'm encountering is my result looks like this:

```
Variable_1=c(123,100,12,212,334)
Variable_2=c(100,212,13,112,300)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subset the RHS of your assignment expression as well.

```
df$Variable_1[df$Variable_1 == 0] <- df$Variable_2[df$Variable_1 == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great.  I was playing around with ifelse earlier as nrussell suggested, but my actual df is too large and ifelse too way too long to run.  This solution is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ifelse` for this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Variable_1 = c(
    123,0,12,0,334),
  Variable_2 = c(
    100,212,12,112,300))
##
df$Variable_1 <- ifelse(
  df$Variable_1==0,
  df$Variable_2,
  df$Variable_1)
##
> df
  Variable_1 Variable_2
1        123        100
2        212        212
3         12         12
4        112        112
5        334        300
```